# Problemas con flip card en IE 11

Tags: html, css

Hola a todos(oootra vez), me han pedido un favor que he hecho con gusto, pero los favores siempre se pagan caro. Me han pedido que añada un flip card para que cuando en la web la gente vaya a TEAM vean el team y al pasar el ratón por encima vean la info de contacto....Hasta aquí todo bien.
El problema viene cuando me vuelven a llamar diceindo que no va en IE 11.
Llevo todo el dia con esto, ya va mas o menos,pero la imagen vibra al girar el flip card y el ultimo desaparece y aparece. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
Os dejo el codigo y el link de la web.

HTML

```
<div class="container-a">
  <div class="ateam">
    <?php 
    $Team = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'category_name'  => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

    $Team_query = new WP_Query( $Team );

    if ( $Team_query->have_posts() ) : 
      while ( $Team_query->have_posts() ): 
        $Team_query->the_post(); 
    ?> 
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </div>
        <div class="back">

          <div class="team-border">
            <div><h1><?php echo the_title();?></h1></div>

            <div class="team-contenta"><?php echo the_content();?></div>

            <div class="team-btns">
              <a class="team-btn" 
                href="tel:<?php echo (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tel', 'true' )); ?>"
                ><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/btn_tel.png" /></a>
              <a class="team-btn" 
                href="mailto:<?php echo (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mail', 'true' )); ?>"
                ><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/images/btn_mail.png" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();  endif; ?>  
</div>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.flip-container:hover .back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
    width: 350px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flipper {
    transition: 1.0s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 1.0s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F29400;
    height: 347px;
}
```

[URL de la web](http://www.kirchnerarchitekten.de/team/)

P:D: aqui el codigo de contenedor tambien

```
.container-a {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.team {
  display: flow-root;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.ateam {
  display: flow-root;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.back-info {
  margin: 60px;
  border: 3px solid #9c9e9f;
  width: 230px;
}

.team h1,
.ateam h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.team-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.team-contenta {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.team-btns {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.team-border {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 3px solid #9c9e9f;
}
```

GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO!!!

Comment: ¿Tendrás un código funcional donde se puedan hacer pruebas?

Comment: aqui te dejo el link: https://jsfiddle.net/Saggi/0yudkkxd/1/